# Reading a .m file from the terminal in an HPC

Tags: files-and-directories, remote-access, high-performance-clusters

I've written a Mathematica notebook and subsequently saved it as a `.m` file, so that I can run it on an HPC. When I opened it, the `.m` file had the form

```
::Package::

::Input::

 "some code"

::Input::

 "some code"
```

and so on. When I tried to get the Mathematica module on the HPC to run this file it spat out a syntax error saying that `::Package::` and `::input::` are undefined. I have to admit, I usually run everything in a Mathematica notebook in the front-end of the Mathematica software, so I'm unsure if I'm using the `.m` file correctly. What is the problem here?

Comment: That looks like a package file. When I run on the HPC (which isn't very often), I copy the input cells into a text editor and save as a plain text file.

Comment: @KraZug        I've also tried copying the inout cells and pasting them into a text editor, then saving it as a `.m` file. The problem I'm finding is that when I try to create an `Interpolation` function using `ParallelTable` and then use this resulting function in an `NIntegrate` it is not being passed to the sub-kernels correctly and so prints the error that the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values. I really don't understand why this is happening as I've defined all the functions/variables in `ParallelEvaluate`. I thought it might be to do with the file format, hence asking this.

Comment: That sounds like a completely separate question.

Comment: That output looks strange. Normally it would be `(* ::Package:: *)`, i.e. those things would be commented. Only initialization cells or code cells will be exported without being commented.

Comment: @Szabolcs      I naively uncommented everything as all of my code cells were commented out as well. Is there a way to separate code cells in a `.m` file, i.e. so they are evaluated individually?

Comment: @Szabolcs      I think I've been doing the whole `.m` file thing wrong - I haven't been setting the cells to initialisation cells. This might explain the problems I've been having.